# Weasyprint page-break-after not functioning properly

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, weasyprint

I have a jinja template and am using weasyprint to make a pdf from it. Currently, it loops through sections of data, and after each section I want to have a page break, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

If I do this:

```
        {% for stuff in stuffs %}
        # do stuff
        <p style="page-break-after: always;" ></p>
        {% endfor %}
```

and it is 3 sections in the for loop, I get no breaks in between sections, but a random extra blank page at the end.

However if I do

```
        {% for stuff in stuffs %}
        # do stuff
        <p style="page-break-after: always;" ></p>
        <p style="page-break-after: always;" ></p>
        {% endfor %}
```

Adding the page break twice, it successfully breaks on the sections, but also adds some extra blank pages through the middle and 2 blank pages at the end.

I'm not sure why this is happening, it seems like weasyprint only recognises to add page breaks when I add them twice, but then goes extra and adds a bunch of blank pages.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up moving to pdftk instead